# Loop through columns and compare columns with similar name in R

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns

me again to ask about loop through column in R. I've the data with pairs as below:

```
a1.x a2.x a3.x a1.y a2.y a3.y 
2     1    2    2    3    2
1     1    3    2    2    3
4     2    2    1    2    4
```

Actually, I have 45 paires like this and I would like to compute the t-test, and calculate other things, and save the values for each pair in one table. Therefore, I wonder whether I can write a loop to do this.

I've tried to do as below:

```
name <-colnames(df[1:45])
name <-gsub(".x", "", name)

for (i in name){

value.x <- paste0(i,".x")
value.y <-paste0(i,".y")

t.dmean <- with(df,t.test(value.x, value.y, var.equal = FALSE))

m.case <-mean(value.x)
sd.case <-sd(value.x)
m.ctl <- mean(value.y)
sd.ctl <- sd(value.y)

d <-(m.case-m.ctl)/sqrt((sd.case^2+sd.ctl^2)/2)

out <-rbind(out, cbind(i,paste0(t.dmean$p.value), m.case, sd.case, m.ctl, sd.ctl, d))

}
```

I expected the table as this

```
scale p_value m.case sd.case m.ctl sd.ctl d
al     0.06    1.1    0.15    1.6   0.5   0.65
a2     0.07    2.1    0.20    2.2   0.10   0.33
a3     0.08    1.3    0.21    1.4   0.2    0.40
```

But this doesn't work...with error msg

```
Error in t.test.default(value.x, value.y, var.equal = FALSE) : 
  not enough 'x' observations
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Does anything know how to do this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function and return all the statistics we want from each group of columns.

```
get_statistics <- function(df) {
      p_val <- t.test(df)$p.value
      m.case <-mean(df[[1]])
      sd.case <-sd(df[[1]])
      m.ctl <- mean(df[[2]])
      sd.ctl <- sd(df[[2]])
      d <-(m.case-m.ctl)/sqrt((sd.case^2+sd.ctl^2)/2)
      c(p_val = p_val, m.case = m.case, sd.case = sd.case, m.ctl = m.ctl, 
        sd.ctl = sd.ctl, d = d)
}
```

and then use `split.default` to split columns by their name and apply the function.

```
t(sapply(split.default(df, sub("\\..*", "", names(df))), get_statistics))

#      p_val m.case sd.case m.ctl sd.ctl      d
#a1 0.006566   2.33   1.528  1.67  0.577  0.577
#a2 0.001894   1.33   0.577  2.33  0.577 -1.732
#a3 0.000493   2.33   0.577  3.00  1.000 -0.816
```

Comment: Thanks both. But actually, I have lots to compute in between...Sorry that I simplified my question too much. I've edited my question.

Comment: @kmY We can write a function to return all the statistics we want to calculate and then apply the function. Updated the answer.

Comment: This works well!!! May I know what is the meaning of `sub("\\..*", "", names(df)`? Thanks very much!

Comment: @kmY it strips of everything after a dot(`.`), from the column names. Run `sub("\\..*", "", names(df))` to see. When we pass this to `split.default` it will split the columns based on similar names. So all `a1` columns are together, all `b1` columns are together and so on. Now for each `a1`, `a2` column it will apply `get_statistics` function.

Comment: I get it! Thanks so much!!